# Value isn't changing for an object's instance

Tags: vb.net, oop

A friend of mine suggested trying to make a Console-based fighting game to help with my vb.net skills. In my game, I can't seem to decrease the enemy's HP by the amount of inflicted damage as I expected. I've attached the important code below.

This is how I calculate the amount of damage to inflict:

```
Player1.Damage = 1 + (Player1.Strength * 2) - 1
Player1.Strength = 1
```

And this is how I use it in an attack to reduce the attacked `_Enemy`'s HP.

```
 Public Sub Attack(ByVal _Enemy As Enemy)
'Enemy is a class
    _Enemy.HP -= Player1.Damage
    Console.WriteLine(_Enemy.Name & "'s HP is: " & _Enemy.HP.ToString & "!")
End Sub
```

An attacks occur repeatedly in a challenge with a selected `Enemy`, like this:

```
Dim _Enemy As Enemy = Enemies(Rand.Next(0, 2))
Dim _EnemyName As String = _Enemy.Name
Console.WriteLine(_EnemyName & " has challenged you!")
Console.ReadLine()
Do While (Player1.HP > 1 Or _Enemy.HP > 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Choose your option:")
    Console.WriteLine("Attack, Flee, Stall, Or Inventory?")
    Opt = Console.ReadLine
    Select Case Opt
        Case "Attack"
            Attack(_Enemy)
            EnemyAttack(_Enemy)
        Case Else
           'There are more cases; they're nonessential.
```

I am expecting that the selected `_Enemy`'s HP decreases after an attack, but it doesn't, it just stays the same.

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening and how I can solve it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the following two lines to your code to figure out what is going on: `Console.WriteLine(_Enemy.Name & "'s HP before attack is: & _Enemy.HP.ToString());` `Console.WriteLine("Inflicted damage is: " & Player1.Damage.ToString());`

Comment: Thanks; hadn't realized that the formula I'd set for Player1.Damage was canceling itself out and equaling zero.

Comment: Lol, that is what I figured. If you read how things work on SO, you now have 3 options: (1) delete your question (2) write an answer to your own question (3) have me convert my comment to an answer to your question. If you feel that your question may have value to other people running into similar issues in the future, options (2) or (3) are the best. This would require you to [edit] your question so that (a) it's title sounds like what they would search for if they had a problem like yours and (b) it contains just the parts relevant to the problem (e.g. tried x, expected y, got z, why?).

Comment: Well, I can't accept my own answer for two days. I guess I'll wait it out.

Comment: I edited your question. You may want to edit your answer to explain better (1) that the HP did not change because you were subtracting a `Damage` value of  `0` (2) how you detected that, and (3) **why** the calculated `Damage` value was `0` (4) how you fixed that. If you do that, you might get some upvotes on your answer ;-)

Comment: Just saying, `Player1.Damage = 1 + (Player1.Strength * 2) - 1` is the same as: `Player1.Damage = (Player1.Strength * 2) `, and don't know what reason would you have to modify character Strength to 1 by default after doing an attack...

Comment: I plan on the strength and HP changing with levels which will be added later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, it seems as though removing the "- 1 " from the Damage formula for Player1 has fixed the problem. It was canceling out in the Damage formula, so it equaled zero. Since any number minus zero doesn't change, the HP wasn't affected.